# How do I set a top margin inside of a box in css?

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(26, 175, 212);
    display: inline;
    margin: 500px;
}
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with box being the parent class but I tried doing this:

```css
.box header {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(26, 175, 212);
    display: inline;
    margin: 500px;
}
```

but the header would be completely gone.

I also tried setting a top margin and setting display:inline-block based on what others have suggested but it completely gets rid of the header.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: ```html
<div class="box">
                <div class="header">
                        <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
.box{
  width: 500px
  height: 500px;
}

.box header{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding-top: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: It worked by doing .header{} instead of .box header{}, can you explain why that is? .box is the parent class of .header which is confusing me, figured your approach would work.

Comment: @azimov308 - Be sure to add a period before your classes. If "header" is a class, then you need to do `.box .header{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a margin inside you can use padding.

```
.box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```